# How to train azure speech to text model on localhost

Tags: docker, containers, speech-to-text, azure-speech

For demand, I can't use azure speech to text service on the cloud. Therefore, I use azure speech to text container with docker. I use two images

1.mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/speechservices/speech-to-text:3.7.0-amd64-zh-tw
2.mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cognitive-services/speechservices/custom-speech-to-text:3.7.0-amd64-zh-tw

I use language zh-tw

I need to train my own speech to text model with custom-speech-to-text. I only find cloud solution on azure. Does anyone know how to train my own model on localhost?

I can can run speech to text container on localhost now but I don't know how to train model on localhost

Answer (score 0):

Training of custom speech models is only available in the Azure cloud through the Speech Portal or Rest API. We don't support training of custom models as a container.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).